Try signing in with a different account ( Next Auth )
Trying to login using Google Provider, facing error Try signing in with a different account. ,

I'm trying to setup an OAuth using next-auth provider (google provider).
In the google cloud console, inside credentials, I've added Authorised redirect URIs  to this http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google as provided in the next auth documentation

im stuck on this. Any solutions?
